# Angular: Rendering any input component dynamically?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

So I'm making a simple component library, and one item I am wanting to make is a simple grid that can take an array of components as input and place them into a grid with standardized styling. However, the tricky part is that I do not know what the input component will be. Is there a way to make the template dynamic to account for the fact that I will not know what the components selector will be?

i.e.

ts file would have

```
 @Input() gridItems: any[]
```

and the template would be something like

```
<div *ngFor="let gridItem of gridItems">
      <grid-item-selector></grid-item-selector>
</div>
```

is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Does this answer your question => https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader#loading-components ?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I needed, thank you!